# How to fill a large area with blocks using command blocks in MC 1.7.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am building a massive fortress in creative and would like to be spared the monotomy of putting the floor in. I have access to commands and command blocks.

The modded server I am using is for running Minecraft version 1.7.2, and I can't update it because I'm not the server owner. Unfortunately this version does not have the `/fill` command at disposal, so I can't use that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a utility to replace one block type with another within a region?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27771/is-there-a-utility-to-replace-one-block-type-with-another-within-a-region)

Comment: In principle there could be a distinct question here, but in practice this question has attracted answers only that ignore the version restriction and suggestions to use plugins/mods, both of which are much better covered by the duplicate question.

Comment: @pppery We shouldn't judge a question by its answers, however. Those answers can be flagged.

Comment: There's no flag for incorrect answers, and in any case the answers aren't really incorrect, just lower-quality duplicates of the answers to the other question.

Comment: @Joachim My judgement leads me to believe that MCEdit and other editors, as of now, are *far* inferior to `/fill`, so it should always be suggested first. Therefore, editing the other question to generalize it will justify this question's closure.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 But the /fill command is only for MC 1.8 and up, right? So generalizing won't work.

Comment: @Joachim I guess in that case, we'll need to edit this question to make it *bloody clear* that it is in 1.7 and `/fill` did not exist at that point.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I feel like that is *bloody clear* if one is willing to read the *bloody question* :D

Comment: @Joachim I guess so lol... I might make a minor edit soon tho if I feel like it, you never know...

Answer (score 4):

There's not an automatic way to do this in 1.7.2. If you're willing to be patient for 1.8 to come out, you can use the `/fill` command.

1. Go to one corner of your castle and press F3. Write down the coordinates.
2. Go to the opposite diagonal corner in your castle and write down those coordinates too.
3. Open the console, and type `/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 gold_block` with the above coordinates. This fills your entire castle floor with gold blocks.

Comment: I believe it's supposed to be gold_block **not** solidgold

Answer (score 2):

or, if you're impatient, you can use the snapshots for a quick access then return to the current version (unless you're doing this on a server)

Answer (score 0):

LavaTaco, another  way to solve this is to use bukkit on the server. Install world edit, do //wand, select the floor, and set it to whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

I am running on 1.7.10 with a lot of mods (with Forge) so I couldn't get a temporary 1.8 with this.

I ended up with this mod, [WorldEdit], which provides a lot of commands for easy world building. To fill a cubic area, I did the following:

- Get a "wand" with `//wand` command (yes, some WE commands begin with two slashes, not one)
- Left-click and right-click two blocks in the to corners. This creates a selection of the cubic area marked by those two blocks

  - If either of them is air, use `/setblock` to turn it into a solid block first (it's a MC builtin command)
- `//set obsidian` and the area is filled with Obsidian, replacing everything.

A full reference of WE commands can be found [here](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Reference).

---

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with that mod.

Answer (score -2):

You do /fill ~1 ~100 ~1 ~25 ~25 ~25 minecraft:stone to make a giant floating block.

Comment: The question is asking for answers in JE 1.7.2. /fill was added in 1.18. 

https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands/fill#History