# Is there a way to keep a minecraft chunk without using a portal and commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play on a Minecraft server and I have made a creeper farm some of it is in the overworld and some in the nether using a nether portal. Is there a way to keep this chunk loaded without me in it and without portals?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking how to keep a chunk (or chunks) *loaded*?

Comment: Some additional questions: 1) Java or Bedrock; 2) do you have op or other special permissions on the server; and 3) what are the creeper farm's X/Y/Z coordinates?

Comment: Note: 1. Without player presence no creepers will spawn. Creepers spawn within 128 blocks around a player, keeping chunks loaded doesn't change that. 2. If the creepers are sent to the Nether through a portal, they portal loads its surroundings (3x3 chunks) for 15 seconds since last creeper passing through (with spawn rates good enough - continuously as long as more creepers pass through). So no other mechanisms required if you keep the Nether part compact enough. 3. Any player more than 128 blocks away from the farm's portal and its creepers in the Nether will cause them all to despawn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keeping chunks loaded in minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/317903/keeping-chunks-loaded-in-minecraft)

Comment: @pppery Are you sure? The asker hasn't stated they are open to cheats and mods to accomplish their task, your suggested duplicate explicitly states that cheats and mods are allowed there, but I sense from this post that they may not want that.

Comment: Ugh this is [How to fill a large area with blocks using command blocks in MC 1.7.2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/170168/185203) all over again; a theoretically distinct question that has acquired answers that technically answer the question but are practically redundant (although there is [an answer that doesn't use cheats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/317916/185203) on that question). Although I did miss that in my original read-through, I continue to feel this is a duplicate for the same reason as the case I linked to.

Comment: I should probably post a question on Meta about what to do with this sort of question. (But knowing me, I'll never get around to it)

Comment: Or have a moderator merge the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Try `/forceload`. It keeps chunks loaded without any player in it. Here's the command:

```
forceload add x z
```

Where `x` is your x coordinate and `z` is your z coordinate.