# Command to replace all blocks of one type with another

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am building a structure with purpur blocks but I am unhappy because I don't like the look of purpur blocks.

I'm looking for a command that can replace the purpur blocks with dark oak wood planks and the purpur pillar with dark oak wood logs.

Comment: if you can edit in co-ordinates you should, not say you can

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a utility to replace one block type with another within a region?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27771/is-there-a-utility-to-replace-one-block-type-with-another-within-a-region)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `/fill` command.

Note the coordinates of one of the corners of your building and the one diagonally opposed:
[image]

Then use them in your command:

`/fill x y z x2 y2 z2 <block> <block variant> replace <block> <block variant>`

- `x y z` are the coords of the first corner
- `x2 y2 z2` are the coords of the other corner
- the first block takes the block you want to have (use `air` to simply remove blocks)
- the second block is the one you want to be replaced with the first one
- `replace` is the magic part telling minecraft to replace blocks

So in your case this should do:

`/fill x y z x2 y2 z2 planks 5 replace purpur_block`
`/fill x y z x2 y2 z2 log2 1 replace purpur_pillar`

Comment: Thank You. I really appreciate you helping me and i found this to be working for me