# In vanilla Minecraft 1.12.2, without using other tools, is there a way to remove one block and change it with another?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft 1.12.2, is there a way to remove a series of stone and change it with air without breaking or changing other blocks?

Comment: @MBraedley i'd argue it's only a related question, as it wants a way to do it without updating/changing nearby blocks.

Comment: @moonheart08 No, I don't think they're talking about avoiding block updates.

Comment: Primarily, this question asks about doing it without external tools. While the other - just the opposite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a utility to replace one block type with another within a region?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27771/is-there-a-utility-to-replace-one-block-type-with-another-within-a-region)

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, only know of one way, and I do not believe it fulfills the second criteria (No changing other blocks) to a point, but it's the best you can get without MCEdit or WorldEdit

## setblock

The setblock command allows you to replace one block with another block of any type when cheats are enabled. It will also tick other blocks nearby the replaced block to allow them to update and adjust to the newly added block.

It's syntax is as follows (May not be precise, cannot see wiki right now)

```
/setblock <posx> <posy> <posz> <newblock>[state=value] [<mode>]
```

An easy way to replace a block is to simply replace the block directly under you, using `~`, the Relative Position variable.

```
/setblock ~ ~-1 ~ <newblock>[state=value] [<mode>]
```

You can add or subtract numbers from `~` to change the position to where you like.