# How to turn sand into grass in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How would I turn sand blocks into the grass block on Minecraft? Please help.

Comment: You could easily find this with a simple search of " how to change one block to another Minecraft" first result is [Digminecraft](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/fill_replace_water.php#:~:text=In%20Minecraft%2C%20you%20can%20use,blocks%20within%20a%20fill%20range.) on how to use /fill

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I replace all blocks of one type with a different type of block, within a certain region?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27771/how-can-i-replace-all-blocks-of-one-type-with-a-different-type-of-block-within)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with commands like this (you need cheats activated).

```
fill ~-10 ~ ~-10 ~10 ~10 ~10 minecraft:grass_block replace minecraft:sand
```

You might need to run the command multiple times, depending on the size of the area in question.

Comment: Answering duplicate questions is counterproductive.

Comment: @pppery this answer was posted before the question was voted as a dupe

Comment: I know, as I was the first dup voter. This is still the sort of thing that people should realize is likely to have been asked before and not rush to answer.